# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy' open cv

Tags: python, opencv, captcha, tiktok

I'm trying to bypass tiktok captcha using openCV running the code below

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('test.png',0)
img2 = img.copy()
template = cv.imread('lol.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
methods = ['cv.TM_CCOEFF', 'cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED', 'cv.TM_CCORR',
            'cv.TM_CCORR_NORMED', 'cv.TM_SQDIFF', 'cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED']
for meth in methods:
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)
    res = cv.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(res)
    if method in [cv.TM_SQDIFF, cv.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED]:
        top_left = min_loc
    else:
        top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
    cv.rectangle(img,top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
    plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(res,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Matching Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
    plt.title('Detected Point'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
    plt.suptitle(meth)

    plt.show()
```

I keep getting hit with the error **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'**

Comment: Do you know which line is erroring?

Comment: do you know the progging language you're trying to use ?

Comment: @Danielme line 5

Comment: Is the file located in your project folder? I can see the problem being a bad file name returning no data and trying to copy an empty cv2 image. You can use 'from os.path import exists' to check 'exists(''test.png'')' and verify your file is correct.

Comment: relative to the *current working directory*. it's always the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're using the correct file name and extension on line 4. The error might come from there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).